# How do i give/show success message after submitting registration form sucessfully

Tags: joomla1.5

I'm new to joomla(using version 1.5.26), i have registration form with several fields, when i submit it blank, it will give required error messages, but after submitting it sucessfully, it dosen't show any success message on the redirected page. 
Please tell me how to show the sucess message on redirected page
Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to show the message in the redirected page or in the same page where your form is there?

Comment: I think on the same page, where registration form is there